# Double Decay Again

Tags: riddle, word

Remove my first, and you have mixed oil

Remove my second, and you'll be close to finding the prime

Remove my third, and you'll speak of yourself

Remove my fourth, and there's nothing left

---

Remove my fourth, and you will laugh

Remove my third, and you will see

Remove my second, and you lose

Remove my first, and there's nothing left

---

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> **[LOLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loli)** - a word referring to a young-looking girl character in Japanese anime and manga.

*Remove my first, and you have mixed oil*
*Remove my second, and you'll be close to finding the prime*
*Remove my third, and you'll speak of yourself*
*Remove my fourth, and there's nothing left*

> Remove the first letter (L) and you are left with **OLI**, an anagram of 'OIL'.
>
>  Next, remove the second (O) and you are left with **LI**, the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) - a good approximation for the prime-counting function in mathematics.
>
>  Next, remove the third (L) and you are left with **I** ('myself').
>
>  Remove the fourth (I) and nothing remains...

*Remove my fourth, and you will laugh*
*Remove my third, and you will see*
*Remove my second, and you lose*
*Remove my first, and there's nothing left*

> Instead, start with LOLI and remove the fourth (I) - you are left with **LOL** ('laughing out loud').
>
>  Next, remove the third (L) and you are left with **LO**, meaning 'Look!' or 'Behold!'
>
>  Next, remove the second (O) and you are left with **L**, an abbreviation for 'lose' or 'loss' in sports.
>
>  Finally, remove the first (L) and again you are left with nothing!